# Error adding TtmMapping

Tags: publishing, web8, topology-manager

I am getting the error below, while trying to add a mapping between the website and Publication for publishing the content.

```
 Add-TtmMapping -Id visitorwebmapping -PublicationId tcm:0-2-1 -WebApplicationId VisitorWeb_RootWebApp Add-TtmMapping : Item of type 'WebApplicationData' with id 'VisitorWeb_RootWebApp' does not exist.
    > At line:1 char:1
    > + Add-TtmMapping -Id visitorwebmapping -PublicationId tcm:0-2-1 -WebApplicationId  ...
    > + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    >     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Tridion.Topolog...dMappingCommand:AddMappingCommand)
    > [Add-TtmMapping], DataServiceException
    >     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Tridion.TopologyManager.Automation.Cmdlets.AddMappingCommand
```

I have defined the Business Process Type and have filled in the Publication URI correctly, but still I get the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error:

> Item of type 'WebApplicationData' with id 'VisitorWeb_RootWebApp' does not exist.

Is trying to tell you there is no web application with the ID `VisitorWeb_RootWebApp` in the Topology Manager, so you might want to check the results of `Get-TtmWebApplication` and see if you didn't misspell it (case sensitivity etc.)